# Concat query result and merge different result in list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

suppose below tables:

**tblColor:**

```
id - name  
1 - red  
2 - blue  
3 - green
```

**tblProducts**

```
id -  name  
1 - TV   
2 -  radio
```

**tblProductColors**

```
id - productId - colorId  
1 - 1 - 1  
2 - 1 - 2  
3 - 2 - 2  
4 - 2 - 3
```

then i can get query by EF Linq as:

```
name - color  
tv - red  
tv -  blue  
radio - blue  
radio - green
```

but i need to get:
tv red,blue
radio blue,green

i think it's not good idea to loop after query and make a list
also i think, must be a quick performance for this solution
**my main problem is speed of result**

thank you

Comment: I imagine the result takes an infinite amount of time to arrive when you have no code :)

Comment: What is `tbl..` prefix for tables name mean?

Comment: If "speed of result" is main problem, then save all required data in one row `1, "tv", "red"`, `2, "tv", "blue"`. Then you will be able to retrieve data without extra joins.

Comment: You really need to include the code you've used to try to solve this, and then ask a specific question about what problem you're having. 

I'm confused why you think speed of result is your main problem when you don't even have a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq's `GroupBy` will be what you are looking for.

As a starting point, to get the list of products with their associated colours...

```
var results = context.ProductColors
    .Select(x => new {ProductName = x.Product.Name, ColorName = x.Color.Name})
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductName)
    .ToList() // Needed for the string.Join since EF won't understand that.
    .Select( group => new 
    {
        ProductName = group.Key, // Product.Name
        Colours = string.Join(", ", group.Select(x=> x.ColourName)); // Colour.Names
    }).ToList();
```

Edit: To avoid the extra `ToList`, select the results into a ViewModel and have the ViewModel format the colours:

```
public class ProductColourSummary
{
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public List<string> Colors { get; set; } = new List<string>();

   public string FlattenedColors
   {
       get { return string.Join(", ", Colors); }
   }
}
var results = context.ProductColors
    .Select(x => new {ProductName = x.Product.Name, ColorName = x.Color.Name})
    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductName)
    .Select( group => new ProductColorSummary
    {
        ProductName = group.Key, // Product.Name
        Colours = group.Select(x=> x.ColourName).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Then to display the results use result.ProductName and result.FlattenedColors.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - That .ToList() that you removed would be required for the use of `string.Join()`. I'd commented it as I wasn't sure, but since checked. Ideally the end solution would be able to select details into a list of results as a view model and the view model will combine the colour values. I will revise my answer.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, Sorry! I thought it differently. May be your are correct as I did not check wether `string.Join(", ", group.Select(x=> x.ColourName))` will converted to sql expression or not.

Comment: @Steve Py thank you, i am testing your code, but(1- does it work on .net core? 2- what if i want to get product's price too? price=group.product.price?)

Comment: @mohammad-adibi: Yes it will work with EF Core, please check the updated answer for the details. You can add price, and other details from product or Colors, just select them into the anonymous type (or ViewModel). You may need to adjust the grouping depending on where "price" applies. (If it's on the Product, or applies to the Product+Color combination)

Comment: @TanvirArjel - No worries, those doubts about supported functions always crop up when I try answering questions from memory. :)